# How to do proper error handling with the fopen function

Tags: c

I wrote a program that asks the user to enter the full pathname of a file. It will then attempt to open that file from the pathname string provided. I used the standard error checking that most books have recommended, which is to close the program if fopen() returns NULL (which it will do in the case that the file does not exist). When I run the program and enter some random characters when prompted (obviously not a valid filename) my program hangs with a runtime error because it's trying to open that file that doesn't exist.

What is the point of the standard error check (pfile == NULL) if your program has already crashed when it calls fopen()? See below code.

I'm using LabWindows CVI 2017 as my enfironment which uses the clang compiler. See image of run time error.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200

int main (void){

    char buffer[MAX];
    int len = 0;
    FILE *pfile = NULL;

    printf("please enter the full pathname of the file you wish to process.\n");

    fgets(buffer, MAX, stdin);

    len = strlen(buffer);

    buffer[len - 1] = '\0';

    pfile = fopen(buffer, "r");

    if(pfile == NULL){
        printf("not a valid filename, press any key to exit.");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while((c = fgetc(pfile)) != EOF){
        sum += sizeof(c);
    }

    printf("the size of your file is %d\n", sum);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer[len - 1] = '\0';` can be _very bad_.  Use `buffer[strcpsn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: Why `sum += sizeof(c);` instead of `sum++;`?

Comment: neither of the above comments help the original issue

Comment: What is your "runtime error" ?

Comment: What is the behaviour of the program exactly? Hangs and gives a runtime error are two distinct outcomes. Could it be the pathname contains invalid characters? (to the OS)

Comment: see my edited post, it shows the error listed by the program. The only characters I usually type to test this out are a few alphanumeric.

Comment: The program just hangs and I have to force close labwindows CVI.

Comment: This is clearly a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) really.

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: *"my program hangs with a runtime error"* -- this doesn't make sense. It either hangs or produces a runtime error, not both... unless you're considering hanging like a runtime error, which is not. *"What is the point of the standard error check"* -- the point is exactly to check if the file was not correctly opened. *"See image of run time error"* -- I see nothing wrong, I don't know what else you would expect if you just *"enter some random characters when prompted"*... that's obviously not going to be an existing file (and in fact, the error is telling you exactly that).

Comment: But I thought if you enter some random characters, isn't that the same thing as a non-existent file? and If a file is non-existent, shouldn't fopen return NULL and not necessarily cause a crash?

Comment: Yes, it should. I suspect there's some built-in error checking going on in your lab environment. That's not normal behavior of C programs.

Comment: OK, so perhaps the Labwindows environment adds that extra error checking.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs just fine with gcc in the Windows WSL environment (WSL2.0 actually). I wonder if your problem is just the return -1 statement in the conditional check after fopen?

Comment: "if your program has already crashed when it calls fopen()" implies prior UB.  Which can occur with not checking the return value of `fgets()` or using `buffer[len - 1] = '\0';` - depending on input.  Recommend a [mcve]

Comment: I ran your program and it worked as-is, although it gave an answer that was too large by a factor of four.  That error dialog you got must be specific to your IDE.  (It's an ill-advised feature, IMO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* doing the proper error handling. Your program is valid in that respect. However, your IDE does some extra error checking, which is the cause of the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The usual rules for error checking in these sorts of situations are:

1. Do check for error returns.  (You're doing that.)
2. Do print a useful error message.  (You're doing that.)
3. Print error messages to `stderr`.
4. If the error involves a file, do include the filename in the error message.
5. If the error involves a function that sets `errno`, do print the "perror" text" ("No such file or directory", etc.).
6. If you're writing a tool that will be combined into larger scripts, do include the program's name in the error message.
7. If the error occurs due to an input file you're reading, do print the name of that file and the line number.

Adopting rules 1 through 6, an improved version of your error check would be

```
if(pfile == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s: %s\n", progname, buffer, strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

For this to work you'll need both of:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

If that's too much  work, a simpler way is just to call

```
perror(buffer);
```

although this falls down somewhat on rules 2, 6, and 7.